# How do you turn off the 'Auto X-Ray Mode'?

Tags: objects

Every time I enter edit mode, X-Ray is automatically turned on.  I know how to toggle it on and off, but I want the default entry into edit mode to have X-Ray off.  Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe you have the same shortcut for edit mode and xray toggle?

Comment: interesting idea. I think you're onto something with that, although its not quite the problem.  I'm using Hard-Ops addon and one of its pie menus is used to quickly enter object / edit mode. When I use that, it auto turns on xray, but when I enter with normal Blender it doesnt. Your suggestion revealed that, so maybe its an option in Hard Ops I somehow toggled on.  Cant seem to find it still.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t know hardops….

Comment: No worries - I appreciate your suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This can be fixed by turning off the *Toggle X-Ray ON* option for *Modes Pie* in the *MACHIN3tools* add-on preferences.

[image]